# ScrollPane autoresize content horizontal without scroll doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, resize, jscrollpane

So I don't know if it doesn't work or if I expect it to work in a different way but anyway.

I have a org.openide.windows.TopComponent which has three lists with different items. This lists can be hidden by clicking in their names so the height is variable depending on which ones are visible. If the lists total height is bigger that the TopComponent height a scroll bar should appear. If the width changes the elements in the list should rearrange so the list uses the whole width available. So the approach I followed is:

TopComponent

Inside JScrollPane (gives me the scroll that I need). Only with vertical scroll.

Inside JPanel.

Inside the three lists (JScrollPanes with JList) with their respective JLabels to click and hide the content.

So if I follow this pattern everything looks nice and when I change the width making it bigger the elements in the list rearrange to use the new width. But when I try to make it smaller again to the original size the lists stay as they are and some elements hide (there is no enough space for all) as if there was a scroll (horizontal). But there is not! But if I remove the outer scrollpane and I do change the width the lists resize perfectly fine (both when I make it wider and narrower) but I don't have the vertical scroll that I need...

```
public class ViewPalettePanel extends TopComponent {

    fcp = new PalettePanel();
    scroll = new JScrollPane(fcp,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    add(scroll, gbc);
}

public class PalettePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public PalettePanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        lbl1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        scPnl1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        lbl2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        scPnl2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        lbl3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        scPnl3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        lblPadding = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 3, 0, 3);
        add(lbl1, gridBagConstraints);

        scPnl1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scPnl1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 60));
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 3, 0, 3);
        add(scPnl1, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 2, 0, 2);
        add(lbl2, gridBagConstraints);

        scPnl2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scPnl2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 60));
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 3, 0, 3);
        add(scPnl2, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 3, 0, 3);
        add(lbl3, gridBagConstraints);

        scPnl3.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scPnl3.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 60));
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 5;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 3, 0, 3);
        add(scPnl3, gridBagConstraints);
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 6;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        add(lblPadding, gridBagConstraints);
    }
}
```

This is the code that I am using (more or less complete) for the visual part. If I change add(scroll, gbc) to be add(fcp, gbc) the resize I want works but not the scroll.

Any ideas?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding this to the JPanel within the JScrollPane it works but I am not sure if there will be any side effects... (Works fine for me though)

```
@Override
public java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize() {

    int h = super.getPreferredSize().height;
    int w = getParent().getSize().width;
    return new java.awt.Dimension(w, h);
}
```